# How to execute SQL Server 2005 generated database query on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I need to execute a SQL Server 2005 generated database query (mostly stored procedures) in to SQL Server 2008. Is there anything that I need to keep in mind while doing this process...?

When I do above process, script does not execute...

Please help me in this problem

Nilesh Pethani

Sorry for including code in comment...

Here is the sample procedure i use to execute without the any SET command, but still it is not working...

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dvx_web_MICROSITES_LoadMicrosites]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        microsite_id AS ID,
        url as URL,
        [name] as [Name],
        catery_id as CateryID,
        catery_code as CateryCode,
        banner_key as Banner,   
        main_banner_key as MainBanner,
        special_zone_id as SpecialZone,
        homepage_url as MainLink,
        active as Active,
        custom_01 as Custom01,
        custom_02 as Custom02,
        custom_03 as Custom03,
        custom_04 as Custom04,
        custom_05 as Custom05
    FROM
        Microsites
    WHERE
        Active = 1
    ORDER BY [Name] ASC
END
```

Comment: If you have any error messages it will be a good idea to post your code and error message here.

Comment: Check to see if you're using anything mentioned [in the list of breaking changes in SQL 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) - it's a list of things that would have worked in SQL Server 2005 which won't on 2008.

Comment: Here is one sample stored procedure script Here is one sample stored procedure script
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
CREATE PROCEDURE [dvx_web_MICROSITES_LoadMicrosites]
AS
SELECT
microsite_id AS ID,
url as URL,
[name] as [Name],
category_id as CategoryID,
category_code as CategoryCode,
banner_key as Banner,  
main_banner_key as MainBanner,
special_zone_id as SpecialZone,
homepage_url as MainLink,
active as Active,
custom_01 as Custom01,
custom_02 as Custom02,
custom_03 as Custom03,
custom_04 as Custom04,
custom_05 as Custom05
FROM
Microsites
WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY [Name] ASC

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: i have generate database script from sql 2005 with option Generate for SQL Server 2005 and execute that script on sql 2008...is it give me error....?

Answer (score 0):

In your sample procedure why you have ANSI NULL and QUOTED IDENTIFIERS SET TO ON before create proc statement? This will give syntax error and this will not be applied every time the proc is executed in the future. So use these settings inside the sproc.I guess this may be the problem with all your procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Which error does you have?  Your code is correct and you can create te Stored Procedure. Add the error message to your question if you have a error when you are creating the Stored Procedure.

If you have a trouble to call your SP, please, add the call code and the result.

Here I have created simple example:

```
create table test_table (
   a int
)
go

insert into test_table values(10);
go

create procedure test_proc
as
begin
  select * from test_table order by a asc
end  
go

exec dbo.test_proc

drop procedure test_proc
drop table test_table
```